# Android NFC tag (generic reader)

Tags: android, tags, nfc, read-write

I have some Samsung TecTiles NFC tags.
I wrote to the tags using the TecTiles App from Google Play.

When I give the tag to a friend he can't read it. After some investigation I found that he couldn't read the tag because he didn't have the TecTiles app installed.

I tried writing to the tag with several other apps but it seems that when I want to read the tag I have to have the same app used for writing the tag.

Can I somehow write the tag and make it readable by any NFC-reader app? 
Do I have to have a reader-app or do the phone supposed to read the tag on its own?

Thanks.
PB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you write the tags sending NDEF Messages as "Absolute URI" type, or another common type, any app application handling NDEF_DISCOVERED intent using those types will read your written data. It's not necesary to use the same application for writing and then reading.

Check this information:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc.html#creating-records

Comment: I wanted to use some app from the Google Play and not write one on my own. Can I do it with an of-the-shelf app or do I have to write my own?

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nxp.nfc.tagwriter&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5ueHAubmZjLnRhZ3dyaXRlciJd

That application should be fine for your purpose